# Grouping related keys of an RDD together

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a generated RDD with a set of key value pairs. Assume that the keys are [10, 20, 25,30, 40, 50]. The real keys are close by Geographic bins of size X.X meters that need to be aggregated to size 2*X.2*X size.
So in this RDD set I need to aggregate keys that are having a relation between them. Example a key that is twice that of the current key - say 10 and 20. Then these will be added together to give 30. The values will also be added together Similarly the result set would be [30,25,70,50].
I am assuming that since map and reduce work on the current key of an element in an RDD , there is no way to do it using map or groupbyKey or aggregatebyKey; as the grouping I want needs the state of the previous key

I was thinking the only way to do this is to iterate through the elements in the RDD using foreach and for each element pass in also the entire RDD to it.

```
def group_rdds_together(rdd,rdd_list):
    key,val = rdd
    xbin,ybin = key
    rdd_list.foreach(group_similar_keys,xbin,ybin) 

bin_rdd.map(lambda x : group_rdds_together(rdd,bin_rdd))
```

For that I have to pass in rdd to the map lambda as well as custom parameters to the foreach function

What I am doing is horribly wrong; just wanted to illustrate where i am going with this. There should be a simpler and better way than this

Comment: Well, you are definitely going down a wrong path ;-) How many keys do you have (just a rough estimate)?

Comment: I parse a huge CSV to make a RDD every 15 mts; each CSV contains about 100,000 rows  as of now; so it is 100,000 keys